# Javascript to close window while using <button>

Tags: javascript, magento, paypal, magento-1.5

I have a Magento store running inside of a frameset.  Paypal recently updated their framebusting script which ended up disabling our store's ability to process payments.

I've ended up changing the code that renders the Checkout button to launch Paypal in a new window and in that window I've successfully set it up to be able to return to the confirmation page.

However in the original window I'm left with a blank screen inside of our iframe.  What i'd like to do is have this window close when the new window is launched but I'm having difficulty doing so.  This is the code that I'm using:

```
<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?>" class="button btn-checkout" onclick="review.save(); window.open('http://auxout.com/shop/paypal/standard/redirect/')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?></span></span></button>
```

Since this button is inside the `<iframe>` I haven't been able to close the initial window. How can accomplish this?

Comment: was it really necessary to include php code in a javascript question ?

Comment: it's from Magento...nothing I can do about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution was to change  to  and just restyle the link with CSS

Answer (score 1):

window.close to close window but i think you cannot close parent window. Why not open paypal in same window rather than new window

Comment: that's a really good idea :) being in an iframe I looked up an example this situation: http://av5.com/docs/changing-parent-window-s-url-from-iframe-content.html.  I tried editing my code as so :::   <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?>" class="button btn-checkout" onclick="review.save(); parent.change_parent_url('http://auxout.com/shop/paypal/standard/redirect/')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?></span></span></button> but it doesn't work.  I added the script to the parent page but for some reason it's still not firing as expected.